# Cannot commit and rollback transaction in sqlalchemy, postgresql, python stack

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have flask application and need to implement transactions.
I have tried this.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Session = sessionmaker()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
db_session = Session()
try:
    db_session.add(post)
    db_session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    db_session.rollback()
```

I can see rollback in the logs but it does not work and the row inserted but should do rollback.

```
2016-12-27 11:14:49,157 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Then I changed this to

```
try:
    db_session.add(post)
    db_session.flush()
except Exception as e:
    db_session.rollback()
db_session.commit()
```

And this works but I don't know is it a good practice or not.